# jquery ui tooltip, display a list tooltip

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, angularjs, jquery-ui-tooltip

I have an array of data that I want to display in a tooltip. That being said, it seems that the tooltip expects a single long string of input. I joined my array by commmas but when I send it in, I want to display it as a list, not a long string.

Here is an example of my situation:

In my controller:

```
$scope.data = ["foo","bar","fubar"];
```

In the template:

```
<label for="test">
    <input tooltip id="Test" type="text" title="{{data.join()}}">
</label>
```

In the directive:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs){
    // i have my data array back, but not sure how to display it as a list
    var dataArray = attrs.title.split(","); 
    element.tooltip(); //gives foo,bar,fubar in the tooltip
}
```

Basically, in my tooltip, I want a list like a rendered version of this:

```
<ul>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
  <li>fubar</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Maybe join it with `<br/>`s?  Or `\r\n`s?

Comment: I have tried this but it comes out foo<br/>,bar<br/>,fubar<br/>

Comment: Could you give us a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Join it with `\r\n`s.  See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/4s3Qf/).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fu7a2/2/

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to adjust the tooltip handler to add custom HTML.

```
$("#test").tooltip({
    content:function(){return $(this).attr('title');},
});
```

And then just use `.join('<br/>')` on the array.

See the [jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/) for more stuff.

**See this [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/fu7a2/6/).**

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar problem to this some time ago, I made a quick demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WR76R/

Essentially you would just be creating your own tooltip with the following jQuery. I read about this technique when I was having the problem, I'll try to find the sauce

HTML:

```
<div id='foo'>Foobar</div>
```

Javascript:

```
 var tooltipPosition = function (event, x, y) {
    $('div.tooltip').css({
        top: event.pageY + 10,
        left: event.pageX - 10
    });
};

var tooltipShow = function (event, content, x, y) {
    $('div.tooltip').remove();
    $('<div class="tooltip"><ul><li>foo</li><li>bar</li><li>fubar</li></ul></div>')
        .appendTo('body');
    tooltipPosition(event, x, y);
};

var tooltipHide = function (event) {
    $('div.tooltip').remove();
}


$("#foo").bind({
    mousemove: tooltipPosition,
    mouseenter: tooltipShow,
    mouseleave: tooltipHide
});
```

CSS:

```
.tooltip {
border: 1px solid rgb(153, 188, 232);
border-radius: 4px;
background-color: white;
position: absolute;
z-index: 2;
padding: 3px;
```

}